# Type Error a float is required, Python Error

Tags: python

what is wrong???

```
from random import randint

from math import sin

from math import cos

from decimal import Decimal

gravity = 32

target = randint(1,5280)

print("Your target is " + str(target))

velocity = raw_input("Enter what velocity: ")

angle = raw_input("Enter what angle: ")

time = (2 * (velocity(sin(angle)))/gravity)

distance = (velocity(cos(angle))*time)

print(str(time))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast to floats:

```
angle = float(raw_input("Enter what angle: ")) # same for velocity
```

Comment: Casting to `float` might be better.

Comment: Yes, I just changed it. Looks like a physics problem, we'll want a good amount of significant figures.

Comment: You're using parenthesis like a function call rather than multiplying.

Comment: `time = (2 * (velocity * sin(angle))/gravity)`

Comment: `distance = (velocity * cos(angle) * time)`

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is that angle is supposed to be a float, but you get it from raw_input which, as the name suggests, returns the raw input, ie a string. Since you're assuming the input is a proper floating point integer you can go ahead and use

`eval(raw_input("prompt"))`

for both the numbers. Then you run into a second problem, which is that
 `velocity(sin(angle))`

treats velocity as a function, which it is not afer defining it as a float, if you would like to use a function make sure to use a different name, if you want to multiply by it you should use 
`velocity*whatever`

quick note:
eval() can be very dangerous if you let just anyone enter input since it interprets the input as python code, so be careful with it